# Apache: Allow directory browsing while using DirectoryIndex directive

Tags: apache-2.4, apache2

I have a local Apache 2.4 Docker container.
My global vhost config is the following:

```
LoadModule proxy_fcgi_module modules/mod_proxy_fcgi.so
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName localWeb
    DocumentRoot /app
    ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://php:9000/app/$1
    <Directory "/app">
        Options All Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Directory browsing works when removing `DirectoryIndex` directive, but when it's there I get a `File not found.` web page instead.

I would like to be able to have directory browsing when there is no index.php, index.html nor index.htm in the directory.

Is that possible?

Comment: Do you add a trailing slash when you request a directory? `/foo/` should work, when `/foo` won't.

Comment: Yes, I do, but still get "File not found.". Trailing slash is automatically added.